# D3/SVG. How do I position a child svg element beyond its parent's extent?

Tags: d3.js, svg, hierarchical-data

Using `d3` I have an `svg` element that I want to parent a child `svg` element hierarchy. The twist is I want the children positioned beyond its parent extent:

```
var svg,
    group;

svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",  200)
    .attr("height", 100);

group = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 400 + "," + 300 + ")");

group
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("width", "300")
    .attr("width", "150");
```

If I run this code the rect will be invisible, clipped by its parent. How do I disable this parental clipping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#OverflowProperty)="visible" on the `<svg>` element. E.g.

```js
    var svg,
        group;

    svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width",  200)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("overflow", "visible");

    group = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 400 + "," + 300 + ")");

    group
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", "0")
        .attr("y", "0")
        .attr("width", "300")
        .attr("height", "150");
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

(Note that you probably need to make this full screen in order to see the rect)

Comment: Bingo! Cheers Robert.

Comment: Robert, any thoughts on why overflow is not the default behavior for svg elements? Containment and hierarchy are often independent. I'm thinking planets orbiting a sun. Hierarchical linkages, etc. Really, any nested transformation hierarchy. Just curious.

Comment: Because the SVG specification says so. See the link in the answer.

Comment: The svg2 spec has changed to make `overflow:visible` the default for the outermost svg when inline in html, but not all browsers do that yet.